# How to enable Masonry animation directly at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

On the homepage of the [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library, there is the masonry-effect shown directly at page load. Besides the headline "What is Masonry?" are image-tiles displayed one after another in a beautiful fade effect.

However, running all the examples within the github repo don't animate at page load.

How to archive this?

What i did:

- i cloned the [repo](https://github.com/desandro/masonry).
- i ran "npm install", "bower install", "grunt"
- i opened the example files in the folder "sandbox", one after another.

No error messages are shown in the browser-console. Apparently masonry is working. I can be sure because changes in e.g. the configuration will take effect.

But the effect on page load differs a lot from this one at the homepage of the vendor. There are no animations.

Comment: I don't believe those initial animations of the masonry items are controlled by masonry itself. I think you'll need to apply the animations yourself on page load. Or on each load of item in masonry layout.

Comment: Take a look at https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late response to the original question but I was stumped on the same issue. The trick is to init Masonry with no grid items or items that have `visibility: hidden`. Using the Masonry config option `stagger` will improve the effect even more. After init, add your grid items or make them visible and they should each appear with a zoom effect. Here's [an example](https://codepen.io/damianmoore/pen/OJVXPbK) I modified from one of David DeSandro's.